# CURL statements combine into one

Tags: php, curl, controller

I have a bunch of curl statements in my app controller file. How can I possibly combine them all into one curl statement. Is it even possible. Thanks

```
    // used for curl and curl_post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

    // used for curl_twitter
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'spider');

    // used for curl_post, curl_auth
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($post_data_count));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data_string);

    // used for curl_twitter
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);



    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);C
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same curl statement evey time you should create a function and juste pass by parameter the wanted change.

```
function curlPerform($url, $postfields, $useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13'){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    // used for curl and curl_post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    // used for curl_post, curl_auth
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($postfields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    // used for curl_twitter
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $reponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $reponse;
}

$reponse = curlPerform($yourUrl, $yourPostFields); // Each time that you want to run a curl request just call this function DRY
```

Or use [curl_setopt_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php)

```
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.example.com/',
                 CURLOPT_HEADER => false
                );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```